# Reload Table smoothly with PHP after submitting POST form

Tags: php

Problem:

I'm currently working on a reservation system. I show the reservations in a HTML table (--> if a tenniscourt is reservated on this day and this time then add css class reservated). Now i also added a cancel method which works perfectly. But now i have the Problem that after i delete the reservation out of the Database it won't reload the table.

I use `echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";` to refresh the page (but it doesn't look smoothly). The problem with this solution is that my Bootstrap Success Alert will also be "deleted" from the page.

Is there any other option to only refresh the tabledata?

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['stornieren'])) {
    $reservationIdInputHidden = isset($_POST['reservationIdInputHidden']) ? $_POST['reservationIdInputHidden'] : "";
    $resController->storniereReservierung($reservationIdInputHidden); //HERE I WILL GET A BOOTSTRAP ALERT AS RESPONSE
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="reservationIdInputHidden" id="reservationIdInputHidden" hidden>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" name="stornieren" id="stornieren" value="stornieren">Reservierung stornieren</button>;        
</form>
```

Comment: You probably don't even have to refresh the whole table, only the row that was changed will do. This is usually done with AJAX, see: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_ajax.htm Note that JQuery is often used to do AJAX, for examples: https://www.studentstutorial.com/ajax/introduction

Comment: You should use JavaScript/Jquery to refresh content that is already loaded at the page. PHP works between moment user sends request to the server and untill it generates the content to give back to the user.

So after content is displayed in browser you can use JS to do operations. For example if you don't want to make your users wait for DB, you can simply hide sections of HTML while JS will perform communications with the server via AJAX.